How can I migrate the data from an elastic search index in the us-west-2 region to a new cluster in the us-east-1 region using AWS manual snapshots?
I have set up two elastic search domains - one in the us-east-1 region and another in the us-west-2 region. I have configured a manual snapshot repository in the us-east-2 domain and have successfully taken a snapshot, with the data stored in an S3 bucket in the us-east-2 region.
Now, I would like to know the best way to proceed with the restoration process in the us-east-1 region.
Here is my current approach:
Step 1: I have enabled cross-region replication for the S3 bucket, so that any snapshots taken in the us-east-2(source) region will automatically be replicated to the us-west-1(Destination) bucket.
Step 2: I will register the snapshot repository with the us-east-1(Destination) domain.
Step 3: Next, I will create a snapshot in the us-east-1 region.
Step 4: Finally, I will proceed with the restoration process.
However, after following these steps, I have noticed that the records and searches in the us-west-2 region do not match with those in the us-east-1 region.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or help regarding whether my approach is correct or if there is a better way to achieve the desired restoration.
